# Handling touch events in SurfaceView over Maps API v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm having issues in creating event handler that will be triggered while user moves the map around. There is a `OnCameraChangeListener`, but it is triggered *after* map moving stops.

I have created `SurfaceView` over Maps, and now I have no idea how to handle `onScroll` event from `OnGestureListener`.

Here is the sample code:

```
SurfaceView sv = new SView();
sv.setZOrderOnTop(true);
mapView.addView(sv);
```

...

```
public class SView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable, android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {
...
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    //this worked in Overlay in Maps API v1
    if(gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
...

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    Log.i("test","onScroll");
    return false;
}

...
}
```

If I set `return true` in `onTouchEvent`, `onScroll` is called but than I can't move the Map (which is obvious, the event is consumed), and I don't know how to dispatch event down to Map object.

Anyone knows how to update `SurfaceView` while Map is moved?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have implemented some other solution to solve this problem. What I did - is I placed my GoogleMap inside custom RelativeLayout.
After that `onInterceptTouchEvent` callback works like a charm and underlying map receives touch events as expected

here is my xml:

```
<com.my.package.name.map.MapRelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/map_root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</com.my.package.name.map.MapRelativeLayout>
```

And custom relative layout:

```
package com.my.package.name.map;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MapRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout
{
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public MapRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
    {
        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
        return false;
    }

    private class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY)
        {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                float distanceX, float distanceY)
        {
            //do whatever you want here
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a hacky way of doing it. How do I call the OnInterceptTouchEvent() from my map fragment java class?

Comment: @Quantumdroid `onInterceptTouchEvent` is called by Android. You don't need to call it manually

Comment: I implemented your code as it is (as a separate class from my main activity) but the onIntercepTouchEvent is never called when I moved my map.

Comment: @Quantumdroid did you wrap your map into this custom layout?

Comment: I did. I followed your instructions. Besides adding Log.i("",""); on onCameraChange(); to see if the event was triggered. But no luck.

Answer (score 2):

From: [Android ListView: overriding causes scrolling do not executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261217/android-listview-overriding-causes-scrolling-do-not-executed)

> Have you tried calling `super.onTouchEvent(event)` in your
>   `onTouchEvent` method?
>
> **Edit** - I think you want to return `false` as well in your `onScroll` method.
>
> Then your `onTouchEvent` method should be:
>
> ```
> @Override
> public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
>     if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
>         return true;
>     }
>     return super.onTouchEvent(event);
> }
> ```

Other possible helpful links:

- [Android: how to tell if a view is scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480187/android-how-to-tell-if-a-view-is-scrolling)
- [Adding GestureOverlayView to my SurfaceView class, how to add to view hierarchy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375967/adding-gestureoverlayview-to-my-surfaceview-class-how-to-add-to-view-hierarchy?rq=1)
- [Android onFling not responding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522637/android-onfling-not-responding)
- [OnGestureListener onDown method never gets called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11730425/ongesturelistener-ondown-method-never-gets-called)
- [Overriding onTouchEvent competing with ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194739/overriding-ontouchevent-competing-with-scrollview)