# Android GoogleMap override touch listener

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout

I want to override the android's google maps touch listener.
(means that by swiping on the top of the map it will do something else rather that move the map)

I successfully managed to cancel the current google map swipe gestures by calling `mMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);`.
And now when I swipe on the top of the map it does nothing

Than I tried to setOnTouchListener to the layout witch includes the map, but the map is still not responding.

Note : I tried to call the setOnTouchListener on the layout both after and before I called the setAllGesturesEnabled but unfortunately it did not success.

I don't now if the following information is necessary but here is a list of the packages I have used for my mapsActicity which relate to google maps.

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
```

Additionally I am using JDK 1.7

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try to add a transparent view over your mapView, then your view can listen to the touch events from user. Or you can refer to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121955/handling-touch-events-in-surfaceview-over-maps-api-v2) about handling touch events.